# Flex paste and import to TextFlow

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, copy-paste, flash-builder

**Using an existing textFlow inside a Spark RichEditableText and wants to paste new text into this with the existing text format (ignore paste format).**

Having 2 major problems
**- The format**
When pasting new text I want the exact same format, gets different fontsize in lines with no text.

**- line breaks**
Problem when importing to existing textFlow, so when export to save I need to add the linebreaks.

*using Flash Builder 4, Actionscript 3 and Spark Components.*

**First get the paste text and put it into textarea.**

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();

var s : String = Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData( ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT, ClipboardTransferMode.CLONE_ONLY ) as String;
s = s.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(9),"gm")," ");
s = s.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(10),"gm"),"#break#");
s = s.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(11),"gm"),"#break#");
s = s.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(12),"gm"),"#break#");
s = s.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(13),"gm"),"#break#");
s = s.replace(new RegExp("#break#","gm"),"\n");

var pflow : TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(s,TextConverter.PLAIN_TEXT_FORMAT);
var x : String = pflow.getText(0,pflow.textLength);
var mgr:EditManager = txtArea.textFlow.interactionManager as EditManager;
mgr.overwriteText( x );
```

**When grabbing the text to save I need to change the line breaks else it goes wrong when putting it back.**

```
var text : String = TextConverter.export( txtArea.textFlow, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT, ConversionType.STRING_TYPE ) as String;
text = text.replace(new RegExp("\n","gm"),"<br>");
SlideItemTextVO(_data).text = text;
```